# "Il n'y a qu'en faisant X que Y" is a variant form of "Ce n'est qu'en faisant X que Y"?

Tags: expressions

> Si d'aventure vous deviez la croiser, j'aimerais que vous lui transmettiez ce message de ma part. **Il n'y a qu'en** travaillant main dans la main **que** nous pourrons ...
>
> {vs}: **Ce n'est qu'en** travaillant main dans la main **que** nous pourrons ...

I wonder if "Il n'y a qu'en faisant X que Y" is a legitimate structure with more or less the same meaning as "Ce n'est qu'en faisant X que Y"?

Comment: Courte réponse, oui.

Comment: @Misery Interestingly though, you cannot always use these two structures interchangeably; "c'est de sa faute que X" can never be expressed with "il y a". So I'm curious to find out why both versions work in this specific example.

Comment: Why would anyone ever think that *c'est de sa faute que* can be used interchangeably with an expression that has no connection whatsoever in meaning?

Comment: @Alone-zee La structure que vous présentez en commentaire n'est pas la même que celle de la question.

Comment: @Circeus Oh, please forget about that one, then. :) Do you think "ce n’est qu’à cette fin que X" can be converted into "il n'y a qu’à cette fin que X"?

Comment: @Alone-zee in your question, the locution introuce a complement, not in your second remark. In the latter I don't think you could substitute as it introduces the subject. "Cette fin" corresponds to "nous pourrons..." In your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui.
1/ Concernant vos citations :

```
Il n'y a qu'en <<verbe au participe présent>> que Y
```

est interchangeable avec

```
Ce n'est qu'en <<verbe au participe présent>> que Y
```

Les expressions *Il n'y a qu'en* et *ce n'est qu'en* expriment toutes deux la nécessité d'une action pour atteindre un but donné. Elles sont interchangeables dans ce contexte, pas forcément dans d'autres. Vous pourriez aussi utiliser :

```
Il faut <<verbe à l'infinitif de X>> pour <<verbe à l'infinitif de Y>>
```

Exemples:

```
Il n'y a qu'en mangeant sa soupe qu'on devient grand garçon.
Ce n'est qu'en mangeant sa soupe qu'on devient grand garçon.
Il faut manger sa soupe pour devenir un grand garçon.
```

2/ Concernant votre texte, un peu différent, c'est la même chose. Ouf. Sauf que dans ce cas, X n'est pas un verbe. Le verbe, c'est *faire*, qui est bien au participe présent. Vous pouvez donc vous référer au 1/ :)

3/ Concernant *Il n'y a qu'à cette fin que X'* et *Ce n'est qu'à cette fin que X'*, la construction est différente. X' est une proposition subordonnée mais *Il n'y a qu'à cette fin que* et *Ce n'est qu'à cette fin que* restent interchangeables.

```
Il n'y a qu'à cette fin que je mange ma soupe.
Ce n'est qu'à cette fin que je mange ma soupe.
Il n'y a que pour devenir un grand garçon que je mange ma soupe.
Ce n'est que pour devenir un grand garçon que je mange ma soupe.
```

beurk.